# Rails 4: Merit Gem: DRYing up the PointRules code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, merit-gem

Is there a way to DRY the PointRules class up a bit? I tried this but it didn't work:

```
%w(attr1 attr2 attr3).each do |attribute|
  score 10, on: 'comments#create', do |comment|
    comment.attribute.present?
  end
end
```

It gave me this error:

```
private method `attribute' called for...
```

**FINAL EDIT:**

The answer provided below works plus you can DRY your code even further by doing something like this:

```
%w(attr1? attr2? attr3?).each do |attr|
  score 5, on: ['comments#update', 'users#update'] do |item|
    item(attr).call
  end
  score 10, on: ['comments#create', 'users#create'] do |item|
    item(attr).call
  end
  score 15, on: ['comments#delete', 'users#delete'] do |item|
    item(attr).call
  end
end
```

Comment: comment.pluck(attribute).reject {|f| f.present?} it will return if there are nil objects. I'll give you an answer later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the wait :(

Here is a solution that it might help you

```
%w(attr1? attr2? attr3?).each do |attr|
  score 10, on: 'comments#create', do |comment|
    comment.method(attr).call
  end
end
```

Active Record adds boolean methods for all your columns, so that is why I used the question mark on the columns.

Please let me know if you have any questions.